# RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter auto configuration at interface file

Tags: wifi, usb

I have bought one USB WIFI dongle by this name "EDUP":

> (Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter)

so I have configured the file by this way:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto usb0
#iface usb0  inet static
#  adress 192.168.7.2
#  netmask 255.255.255.0
#  network 192.168.7.0
#  gateway 192.168.7.1
#  broadcast 192.168.7.255
# dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

    #allow-hotplug wlp2s0
    #iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp

    auto wlan0
    allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0  inet dhcp
       wpa-ssid "roshd"
       wpa-psk "rr1393"
```

the output of **ifconfig** is :

```
usb0: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::a383:7ee9:36f9:2027  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether aa:70:b5:c0:6b:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5062  bytes 347070 (338.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10323  bytes 9779116 (9.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ea4e:6ff:fe64:fa65  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e8:4e:06:64:fa:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 61  bytes 6599 (6.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22  bytes 3509 (3.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.108  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9440:4b06:b605:ca01  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c8:3d:d4:3c:23:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 755893  bytes 988980144 (943.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 480126  bytes 53989884 (51.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

the **lsusb** output also is:

```
so@notebook:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:0821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 174f:2408 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 042: ID 0525:a4a2 Netchip Technology, Inc. Linux-USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have run the  **apt-get update** by this configuration this device dont show in my network panel in my (LINUX MINT LMDE), :
[image]

but when i have removed this lines from my  `/etc/network/interfaces` file the wireless icon show my USB DONGEL and it is working:

```
 auto wlan0
    allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0  inet dhcp
       wpa-ssid "roshd"
       wpa-psk "rr1393"
```

, but I want to configure it for my raspberry and I need to use the  `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

SO what I must to do to configure it in  /etc/network/interfaces file automatically?

UPDATE:

Now when i remove those line i also have not access to my USB Dongle as you can see:

[image]
Thanks